# What real-time Open Data do you want to use?

Tags: api, uses-of-open-data, real-time

I work for [OpenSensors.io](https://opensensors.io), we are an Internet of Things company working on making real-time data more accessible, easy to use. We've built a real-time Open Data exchange through which you can publish to, search for, subscribe to and access Open Data like earthquake, air quality or transport feeds through a real-time firehose. All open data projects are free to use too, we only charge if you want to keep the data private. We're partnered with the [Open Data Institute](http://theodi.org/).

We want to provide open data-sets that people want to use. Which begs the question, what real-time data sources to do you most want to see and access? What tools do you need to make use of this data?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure that MQTT is targeted at this but I'd like to have a FX spot and forward quotes available in the open.  Fastmatch operates a good good and open transparency policy providing free quotes for mass distribution (http://fastmatch.com/fees#tape)

Comment: As there's no one specific 'answer' for this question, I've converted it to community wiki.  It's possible that one of the other moderators might move it to meta.opendata.SE ... but then it'd likely get less notice.